# Kth largest element BST

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, tree

Would this take \$O(n)\$ in worst case? Can it be improved?

```
var tree = {
  val: 5,
  left: {
    val: 2, left: null, right: null
  },
  right: {
    val: 6,
    left: null,
    right: {
      val: 8,
      left: null,
      right: null
    }
  }
};

function inorderReverse(node, cb) {
  if (node.right !== null) inorderReverse(node.right, cb);
  cb(node);
  if (node.left  !== null) inorderReverse(node.left,  cb);  
}

// Find the kth largest element
var k = 1;
var count = 1;
inorderReverse(tree, function(node) {
  if (count++ === k) console.log(node.val);
});
```

Comment: WRT your second question: Questions asking for [advice about code not yet written](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic. Please [follow the tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Note: it's 'traverse' and 'traversal'(Latin for 'to travel/pass through'), not 'reverse' and 'reversal'. Cf. Italian 'attraversare'. Also, your solution is already O(k) since the hard work has been done creating and maintaining the binary search tree. You only need to visit k nodes even if the tree is degenerate, but only if you *stop* the traversal once you have arrived at the kth node.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are forced for some reason to use that particular type of datastructure, I think you will end up with an O(k) algorithm.

To deal with the edge case, note that your code arguably works fine if k is too large--it just doesn't print anything.  You could also store the size of the tree and check that.  But you'll have to be careful to keep it updated when you manipulate the tree.

Alternately, you could change your tree-walking code to return a value as soon as it finds one:

```
function reverseFind(node, test) {
  if (node == null) return undefined;
  return reverseFind(node.right, test)
    || test(node) ? node : undefined
    || reverseFind(node.left,  test);  
}

function kthLargest(tree, k) {
  var count = 1;
  var node = reverseFind(tree, function(node) {
    if (count++ === k) return true;
  });
  if (node) {
    console.log(node.val);
  } else {
    console.log('no value');
  }
}
```

This, at least, is O(k), not O(n).

If your data is reasonably static, it is probably better to just store your data in a sorted array.  Then you can get the kth largest element in constant time with much less code:

```
var sortedArray = [2, 5, 6, 8];
function kthLargest(sortedArray, k) { 
  return sortedArray[sortedArray.length - k]; 
}
```

Note that this code assumes that there are no values in the array with negative indices (i.e., that sortedArray[-5] === undefined).  So you can deal with the edge case of invalid k by checking to see if kthLargest returns a value.

Comment: `reasonably static…data in a sorted array` can still be searched by key in the _ld n_ comparisons of a perfectly balanced BST, in addition to unsurpassable positional and iterative access.